# Como acessar valores JSON vindo do ajax numa página PHP?

Tags: php, ajax, json

Passei via ajax esses valores:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/loterias/cadastro.php',
    type: "POST",
    data: "{'numeros': '" + numeros + "', 'jogo':'" + jogo + "'}",
    dataType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (data) {
        debugger;
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function(xhr,err){
        alert("readyState: "+xhr.readyState+"\nstatus: "+xhr.status);
        alert("responseText: "+xhr.responseText);
    } 
});
```

No PHP (cadastro.php) recebi assim (não sei se está correto):

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), TRUE);
```

Como posso dar um echo no valor "numeros" e em "jogo"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A propriedade `dataType` refere-se ao tipo de dado que se espera do servidor, então só use `'application/json'` se pretende retornar a resposta como json...

Para acessar o POST diretamente sem passar por decoder monte o data como uma URI normal:

**Jquery:**

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/loterias/cadastro.php',
    type: "POST",
    data: "numeros=" + numeros + "&jogo=" + jogo,
   // dataType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', // só utilize se o retorno do servidor for em json.
    success: function (data) {
        debugger;
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function(xhr,err){
        alert("readyState: "+xhr.readyState+"\nstatus: "+xhr.status);
        alert("responseText: "+xhr.responseText);
    } 
});
```

**PHP:**

```
print_r($_POST);
```

ou

```
echo $_POST['numeros'];
echo $_POST['jogo'];
```

Answer (score 4):

A função json_decode() com o segundo parametro TRUE transforma o objeto json em um array associativo, tento;

```
$numeros = $data['numeros'];
$jogo = $data['jogo'];
```

Outro aspecto: deve inverter a aspas no objeto json porque para o objeto ser valido no php, o nome e o valor devem estar dentro de aspas duplas "nome":"valor" (no caso de strings)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Você tem razão, o `json_decode` está falhando porque está sendo postado um JSON inválido.